# Use OR with condition in AutoHotkey script

Tags: apache-http-server, script, mysql, automation, autohotkey

I created the following AHK script to answer my own question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1620707/restart-xampp-without-using-the-control-panel/1620708#1620708):

```
NumpadEnter::
Process, Exist, httpd.exe
If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
    Run, C:\XAMPP\apache_start.bat,,Hide
    Run, C:\XAMPP\mysql_start.bat,,Hide
    }
Else
    {
    Run, C:\XAMPP\apache_stop.bat
    Run, C:\XAMPP\mysql_stop.bat
    Sleep, 2000
    Run, C:\XAMPP\apache_start.bat,,Hide
    Run, C:\XAMPP\mysql_start.bat,,Hide
    }
Return
```

However, the script isn't perfect - currently, it only checks for the existence of the Apache process `httpd.exe`, but XAMPP starts both the Apache server and the MySQL database, which uses the `mysqld.exe` process. In the scenario that Apache is down but MySQL is up, it seems like the logic of the script would fail, so I'd like to fix this line:

```
Process, Exist, httpd.exe
```

...to check for the existence of *either* `httpd.exe` or `mysqld.exe`.

AHK has an OR operator, for which you can either use `or` or `||`, but doing:

```
Process, Exist, httpd.exe || mysqld.exe
```

...just attempts to start the servers (i.e running the first block of code, indicating a failure in logic and/or syntax). In other words, it doesn't seem like OR can be used in conjunction with a condition like `Process, Exist`.

Is this possible with AHK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `IF` expression, AHK uses the operator `or` ([Documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)). You could call `Process` twice, store the result each time, and then check if either is `0`.

```
Process, Exist, httpd.exe
errHTTPD := ErrorLevel
Process, Exist, mysqld.exe
errMYSQLD := ErrorLevel
If (errHTTPD = 0 or errMYSQLD = 0)
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

As an alternative that does not directly answer your question but I do think it will work in your particular case:

```
Process, Exist, httpd.exe
IfEqual, ErrorLevel, 0
    Process, Exist, mysqld.exe
```

First, check for `httpd.exe`. If that sets `ErrorLevel` to be `0`, then look for `mysqld.exe`.

Comment: Brilliantly done, the first solution seems to work perfectly.